# Namespace for Reverse Phone, Reverse Zip, and Reverse IP Lookup services

Tags: architecture, naming-conventions, namespaces, naming

I'm looking for ideas/suggestions on a namespace.

I have 3 objects that do the following:

1. Object 1: Reverse Phone Lookups
2. Object 2: Reverse Zip Code Lookups
3. Object 3: Reverse IP Address Lookups

Currently, they are in the following namespaces:

1. (CompanyName).Utilities.PhoneTools
2. (CompanyName).Utilities.AddressTools
3. (CompanyName).Utilities.IPTools

All the objects do similar stuff, namely reverse lookups (ie: If you give a phone number, it will return the address associated with that phone).  It doesn't feel right that they all have their own namespaces, and I don't like using a "Utilities" name space.

Anybody out there who has any suggestions on what an appropriate namespace should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the following namespace for all my objects:

- CompanyName.Utilities.Sniffers

And called my main objects:

- AddressSniffer
- IpSniffer
- PhoneSniffer

I also created a few more top level names spaces to hold certain by products of the above classes:

- (CompanyName).Formatting
- (CompanyName).Validation
- (CompanyName).Common

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServices or Identification

```
IdentityServices.Telephones
IdentityServices.Adresses
IdentityServices.Internet

Identification.Telephones
Identification.Adresses
Identification.Internet
```